# Issue when querying Ms-Access database Java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, ms-access

I am trying to make a login page where a user enters their username an password and it is checked in the database and whether or not the record is found the user would be granted access to the rest of my program. But for some reason there seems to be an issue with my database query and I cannot quite figure out why.

My code is below:

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                try
                {
                    String userInput = txtUsername.getText();
                    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/Documents/School/IT/2020 PAT Database.accdb");
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from tblLoginDetails WHERE Username = " + userInput);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    ResultSetMetaData rsd = rs.getMetaData();
                    String ID, username = "", password, isAdmin;
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        ID = rs.getString("ID");
                        username = rs.getString("Username");
                        password = rs.getString("Password");
                        isAdmin = rs.getString("IsAdmin");
                        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(txtUsername.getText()))
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Its working!");
                    }
                    
                   
                } 
                //Exception handling for ClassNotFoundException and SQLException:
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class Not Found\n"+e);
                } 
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input\n"+e);
                }
            }
        });
```

When i click on the login button I get an input error saying that the object is not found or user lacks privilege. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add stack trace! Your query is wrong ("select * from tblLoginDetails WHERE Username = " + userInput) as strings have to be surrounded by string literal delimiters (`'` or `"`) also concating criterias is causing [sql-injections](http://www.bobby-tables.com) use parameters as already using a [prepared statement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html)! And never store passwords! store hashes!